# SQL Server : concurrency issue in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, concurrency

I am implementing sequence in SQL Server 2008 and I found [this article form MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2006/04/10/sql-server-sequence-number.aspx)

In the stored procedure `usp_GetNewSeqVal`, the author is getting the next sequence like this:

```
update AllSequences
set @NewSeqVal = CurrVal = CurrVal+Incr
where SeqName = @SeqName
```

This seems problematic to me, it seems like the lack of row lock will potentially create a concurrency issue.

But in the article he is stating:

*Concurrency – the execution of extended procedure is not within the transaction scope of the DML statement, and it holds very short duration locks on the row that represents the sequence number.*

Is there a concurrency issue here?

If so how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, there is **NO** concurrency issue ! That's why it's such an elegant solution!

The `UPDATE` statement will take an `Update` (U) lock while reading the existing value - and the `U` lock is already **exclusive** in that a second `update` **cannot** proceed at this point. If a second connection also tries to update the same counter, it will have to **wait** until the first `UPDATE` statement is done in its entirety.

The lock is then upgraded to an exclusive (X) lock to write back the new value while at the same time storing it into the `@NewSeqVal` variable.

This use of a **single**, atomic `UPDATE` ***prevents*** any concurrency issues!

Comment: Prevents some concurrency issues. But if that atomic update is part of a bigger transaction, and there are enough big transactions that need to make that update, then this could bottle neck.